# Share a function between two passes inside CG Shader for unity3d

Tags: function, unity-game-engine, shader

I'm writing a shader in CG language for Unity3d.
If you make a shader for transparent object you need to create two similar passes in `SubShader`. The first one to render only back faces (with `Cull Front`) and the second one to render only front faces  (with `Cull Back`). But the code for vertex and fragment function is the same for two passes.

Is it possible not to double a code and declare some functions, that would be shared between passes?
I want to have something like in my code example:

```
Shader "cool shader" {
Properties {
    ...
}
SubShader {

    CGPROGRAM
    // need to declare vertexOutput somewhow here
    float4 sharedFragFoo(vertexOutput i) : COLOR  // How to make smth like this?
    {
        ....
        return float4(...);
    }
    ENDCG

    pass {
        CGPROGRAM
        #pragma vertex vert
        #pragma fragment frag
        vertexOutput vert(vertexInput v) {
            vertexOutput o;     
            ...
            return o;
        }

        float4 frag(vertexOutput i) : COLOR
        {
            return sharedFragFoo(i); // call the shared between passes function
        }

        ENDCG
    }

    pass {
        CGPROGRAM
        #pragma vertex vert
        #pragma fragment frag
        vertexOutput vert(vertexInput v) {
            vertexOutput o;
            ...
            return o;
        }

        float4 frag(vertexOutput i) : COLOR
        {
            return sharedFragFoo(i); // call the shared between passes function
        }

        ENDCG
    }
}
}
```

**UPD:** Found out how to do it using includes.
 But is it possible to do inside **one** file?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Answering my own question. Wierdo!
Hope it will help somebody else.

You can write all that betwee `CGPROGRAM` and `ENDCG` in separate ***.cginc** file and include it inside each pass.
**Important!** But you need to write 
`#pragma vertex vert` and `#pragma fragment frag` inside your main shader file, otherwise it will compile but won't work. I suppose that the reason is that *pragma'ss* are processed before *include's*.

Here is my code sample.
Main **shader definition file:**

```
    Shader "cool shader" {
    Properties {
        // properties
    }
    SubShader {
        ...

        pass {
            Cull Front
            ZWrite Off
            CGPROGRAM
            #pragma vertex vert
            #pragma fragment frag
            #include "shared.cginc"
            ENDCG
        }

        pass {
            Cull Back
            ZWrite Off
            Blend SrcAlpha OneMinusSrcAlpha
            CGPROGRAM
            #pragma vertex vert
            #pragma fragment frag
            #include "shared.cginc"
            ENDCG
        }
    }
}
```

Shared file **shared.cginc:**

```
#ifndef SHARED_FOO
#define SHARED_FOO

uniform sampler2D _MainTex;
uniform float4 _MainTex_ST;
uniform float4 _Color;
// other variables....

struct vertexInput {
    float4 vertex : POSITION;
    float3 normal : NORMAL;
    float4 texcoord : TEXCOORD0;
};

struct vertexOutput {
    float4 pos : SV_POSITION;
    float4 tex : TEXCOORD0;
    float4 posWorld : TEXCOORD1;
    float4 posInObjectCoords : TEXCOORD2;
    float3 normalDir : TEXCOORD3;
};

vertexOutput vert(vertexInput v) {
    vertexOutput o;
    // do staff 
    return o;
}

float4 frag(vertexOutput i) : COLOR
{
    // do staff 
    return float4(...);
}
#endif // SHARED_FOO
```

Comment: yeah `#pragma vertex vert` is to specify which vertex function you want the shader to use, otherwise it defaults to something built-in other than the one in your .cginc.

Answer (score 13):

You can do it in one file using `CGINCLUDE`. If you look at the shader for MobileBlur ("Hidden/FastBlur") by Unity it has shared code at the top and passes below.

Here are just the key parts - note `CGINCLUDE`/`ENDCG` outside of the SubShader/Pass

```
Shader "YourShader"
{
    ...

    CGINCLUDE

    #include "UnityCG.cginc"

    struct shared_v2f
    {
        float4 pos : SV_POSITION;
    }

    shared_v2f myVert( appdate_img v )
    {
        shared_v2f o;

        o.pos = mul (UNITY_MATRIX_MVP, v.vertex);

        return o;
    }

    fixed4 myFrag( shared_v2f i ) : SV_Target
    {
        return fixed4( 1.0, 0.5, 0.0, 1.0 );
    }

    ENDCG

    SubShader
    {
        ...

        Pass
        {
            CGPROGRAM 

            #pragma vertex myVert
            #pragma fragment myFrag

            ENDCG
        }
    }
}
```